# Problem Parsing float in java : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[60.0]"

Tags: java

im calling a method to obtain a string with the values that i need. After that i try to transform that string to array list with the float numbers.
The idea is to use a for to get the position of the array to commit each value. 
But the problem is that im getting this error:

**java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[60.0]"**

This is my code:

```
private String obtenerPrecios (String ids) {
       System.out.println("ids parametro: :" + ids);
       try{

            Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            List<String> listaIds = new ArrayList<String>();
            //System.out.println("ids lista: :" + listaIds);
            List<String> idsList = Arrays.asList(ids.split(","));
           // System.out.println("idsList :" + idsList);
            List<Integer> iList = idsList.stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
            //System.out.println("idsList int :" + iList);
            List result = session.createQuery("SELECT p.precioUnidad FROM Productos p WHERE p.id IN :stringIds").setParameterList("stringIds", iList).list();   
            //System.out.println("resutlado query :" + result);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();

           // System.out.println("precios :" + result);
            //listaIds.toString();
           // System.out.println("lista a string :" + result.toString());
            return result.toString();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        }


   }




    @RequestMapping ( method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public String confirmarVenta (@RequestParam(value = "check", required = true) String checkboxValores,  Model model){

         System.out.println(checkboxValores +":  String con ids");

         try{
            Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            Venta vnt = new Venta();
            Productos prdcts = new Productos();

            int idVenta = generarID();

//            List ids = Arrays.asList(checkboxValores);
            System.out.println(checkboxValores +":  Array con ids");
//            List result = session.createQuery("from Productos where id=" + ids).list();
//            System.out.println(result + "result");
            for( int i=0; i < checkboxValores.length(); i++){
                System.out.println("ids :" + checkboxValores );
                int idP;
                String precioQ;

                idP = Character.getNumericValue(checkboxValores.charAt(i));
                System.out.println("idp :" + idP);
                precioQ = obtenerPrecios (checkboxValores);
                System.out.println("precioQ :" + precioQ);

                List<String> idsList = Arrays.asList(precioQ.split(","));

                System.out.println("idsList :" + idsList);

                Float [] precioLista = idsList.stream().map(Float::valueOf).toArray(Float[]::new);


//                System.out.println("precioLista : " +precioLista);
//                System.out.println("precioLista get clas : " +precioLista.getClass());
//                System.out.println("precioLista I: " +precioLista[i]);

                vnt.setFechaVenta(getCurrentDate());
                System.out.println(idVenta + ": id venta");
                vnt.setIdVenta(idVenta);
//                System.out.println(" precio posicion i: " + precioLista.get(i));
//                System.out.println(" precio posicion i get class: " + precioLista.get(i).getClass() );

                System.out.println("aca llega");
                vnt.setMonto(precioLista[i]);
                vnt.setIdProducto(idP);
                //vnt.setIdUsuario(id); pasar por url el id del empleado y pasarlo como parametro.
                session.save(vnt);
                model.addAttribute(vnt);
                session.getTransaction().commit();

            }
            session.close();
            return "transicionVenta";
         }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return"error";
        }


     }


}
```

and this is the log:

```
Información:   4:  String con ids
Información:   4:  Array con ids
Información:   ids :4
Información:   idp :4
Información:   ids parametro: :4
Información:   precioQ :[60.0]
Información:   idsList :[[60.0]]
Grave:   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[60.0]"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:416)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:545)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:438)
    at Controladores.CVentas.confirmarVenta(CVentas.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: try `Float::valueOf` or `Double::valueOf` in this line `List<Integer> iList = idsList.stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());`. Replace `Integer::valueOf` with what I suggested earlier.

Comment: @Faraz The exception states that the input contains `[` and `]`.

Comment: `"[60.0]"` is not a string with an *integer* number. It is a floating-point number so you should use `Double::valueOf`, not `Integer::valueOf`. But even that will fail, because `[60.0]` is not a number at all. `60.0` is a number. So you need to add logic to remove the square brackets.

Comment: @f1sh I just noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You convert `List` to `String`, which wraps your value into `[]` characters. Then these characters prevent you from splitting your list properly.

Don't do this, just return List itself, or event cast it to `List<String>`. Then you can operate with it easier:

```
private List<String> obtenerPrecios(String ids) {
    // ... your retrieval here ...
    return (List<String>) result;
}

@RequestMapping ( method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String confirmarVenta(@RequestParam(value = "check") String checkboxValores, Model model) {
    // ... your business logic here ...
    Float [] precioLista = obtenerPrecios(checkboxValores).stream()
        .map(Float::valueOf)
        .toArray(Float[]::new);
}
```

Also this makes no sense:

```
    vnt.setMonto(precioLista[i]);
```

Because `i` belongs to array `checkboxValores`, while you use it for another array. Indexes are not guaranteed to match. Most probably this would produce `IndexOutOfBoundException` when size of `checkboxValores` is 2 or more.

By the way, alternatively you may want to return just the first value if your SQL statement is expected to always return a single value:

```
private String obtenerPrecios(String ids) {
    // ... your retrieval here ...
    if (result.size != 1) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Single result is expected from database!");
    }
    return result.get(0);
}
```

P.S.: You don't rollback transaction in case of exception, which may cause additional issues.

P.P.S.: As you already use `Spring Framework`, consider using `JDBCTemplate` - it would help you avoiding common mistakes.

Comment: Hello @stepio, thanks i solved this proble with the information you gave me.